# Getting rid of SettingWithCopyWarning in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am loading a bunch of csvs and processing certain columns if they exist, after loading the csv with pandas

```
data = pd.read_csv('Test.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", index_col=0)
```

this dataframe will be used in the example

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2.1, 0, 4.7, 5.6, 6.8],
                    'B': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    'C': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                    'D': [5, 5, 6, 5, 5.6, 6.8],
                    'E': [2, 4, 1, 0, 0, 5],
                    'F': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                    'G': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],})
```

Next I check and select specific columns that are going be processed

```
coltitles = ['A', 'B','C', 'D', 'E']

columns = []

for name in coltitles:
    if name in data.columns:
        columns.append(name)
    else:
        print (name, 'is missing')

df = data[columns]

if 'A' in df.columns:
    #perform some processing, I will put print to simplify it
    print ('Exist')
```

The code works if I use a dataframe for `data`, but If I load the data from a csv I get a Warning:

```
<module3>:74: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

The warning is caused by the line where `df = data[columns]`.

The code still works with the warning but how do I get rid of this warning without suppressing it?

Comment: Try df = data[columns].copy()

Comment: Is this actually your code, is `coltitles = ['A', 'B','C', 'D', 'E']` ? What is `columns` when the exception happens?

Comment: Hmm, I thought this error could *only occur* if you assign a value to a slice. That is, if you did something like `data[columns] = something` for example. @ccsv are you sure the error is on the line that says `df = data[columns]` -- in which case, could you please paste a full working snippet that reproduces the error?

Comment: @Alexander This worked post a response.

Comment: @SAnand That is the full warning. It is not an error as it still works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The chained assignment warnings / exceptions are aiming to inform the
>   user of a possibly invalid assignment. There may be false positives;
>   situations where a chained assignment is inadvertantly reported.

The purpose of this warning is to flag to the user that the assignment is carried out on a copy of the DataFrame slice instead of the original Dataframe itself.

You generally want to use .loc (or .iloc, .at, etc.) type indexing instead of 'chained' indexing which has the potential to not always work as expected.

To make it clear you only want to assign a copy of the data (versus a view of the original slice) you can append .copy() to your request, e.g.

`df = data[columns].copy()`

See the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) for more details.